# Photo viewer for Windows that preloads next files in folder and allows rotating and deleting images?

Tags: software

I have large collection of photographs, I need to quickly iterate through it deleting unwanted ones and rotating some.

So I want to find photo viewer that can:

1. Preload next image(s) so there is no lag after attempting to view the next image (IrfanView failed here, default Windows 7 image viewer tries to do this but is not always succesful)
2. Rotate images (FastPictureViewer failed here)
3. Iterate properly over files after modificating/deleting one of files
   (default Windows 7 image viewer failed here)
4. Automatically save rotated images (FastStone Image Viewer failed
   here).

Other features are not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XNView](http://www.xnview.com) can preload the next image, it is possible to rotate images (JPGs lossless; it is not working for RAWs, at least not for the flavour I use), it continues as I expect it to do after deleting (don't know if it is "properly" for you), and the lossless JPG rotation is applied immediately so it may be worth a test for you.

Comment: Maybe I am expecting too much but it is not preloading the next image, only thumbnail (it jumps a bit after loading entire file). But it is the first one where I can really quickly move through a folder. In general, I like it and it is free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

[PMView Pro](http://www.pmview.com) is the tool of choice for this. It is the fastest Windows viewing software and provides a very efficient workflow and high degree of customization.

After binding hotkeys CTRL-LEFT-ARROW and CTRL-RIGHT-ARROW to do lossless rotation, clockwise and counter-clockwise respectively, you can easily advance (PgUp / PgDn) and delete (DEL) images at an extremely quick pace.

When using lossless rotation, PMView does not ask to confirm for saving, which is a great touch of logic! If you do multiple cycles over images, it will know which ones are deleted.

Comment: It is not caching the next image, but "efficient workflow and high degree of customization" is really true. Unfortunately it is free only for one month, but I never mentioned that I want a free software (maybe I will make a new question for this one).

Comment: @Bulwersator PMView Pro is such an excellent program that I own several licenses. If you are looking for free, then you'll get what you pay for! Considering that most camera batteries and even the neck-strap I use is more expensive than PMView Pro, it really seems a waste to search for anything else. The only free software which offers a decent experience if Geeqie which I use on Linux. Maybe they have a Windows version or you can run it in a VM.

Comment: I am in a different situation (availability of time/money/skills/etc) and I would rather write my own software than pay for licence. But XNView seems to be okay. "If you are looking for free, then you'll get what you pay for!" - at least with software it is not true, according to my experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is now XnViewMP (free for personal use) which has both 32- and 64-bit processing, supports multithreading, and pre-caches images as you view them. It also has batch-processing capabilities, picture resizing, advanced JPEG encoding options, etc. The only downside are some nasty bugs and weird keyboard shortcuts (which can be customized, to match IrfanView). I tried three different versions, as it upgrades itself, and it is very fast. They also have a Linux version.