# Free photo viewer for Windows that preloads next files in folder and allows rotating and deleting images?

Tags: software

I have large collection of photographs, I need to quickly iterate through it deleting unwanted ones and rotating some.

So I want to find free photo viewer that can:

1. Preload next image(s) so there is no lag after attempting to view the next image (IrfanView failed here, default Windows 7 image viewer tries to do this but is not always succesful)
2. Rotate images (FastPictureViewer failed here)
3. Iterate properly over files after modificating/deleting one of files
   (default Windows 7 image viewer failed here)
4. Automatically save rotated images (FastStone Image Viewer failed
   here).
5. And is free (PMView Pro found thanks to [Photo viewer for Windows that preloads next files in folder and allows rotating and deleting images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49836/27638) fails this)

Other features are not necessary. I prefer open-source projects with active development.

Comment: RAW files or JPEGS only? If RAW, what particular types (i.e. NEF, CR2, etc.)?

Comment: @MichaelClark No RAW files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search, I use XnView MP on daily basis. I answered you in the forums there :).

However I think that's better to repost the gist from there, together new info related to what you asked here:

1. Yes - You need a setting which (IIRC) is enabled by default in Tools | Settings | View | Misc. However, remember that if you move to the next image fast enough the storage layer (HDD/SSD + mobo/controller + a dozen of other processes which read/write from the HDD if you are on the OS disk) will NOT be able to keep the pace. AFAIK, XnView MP is the fastest browser around so I don't think that you can find a better solution for this.
2. You can do this in batch or one by one in Browser mode or in View mode. You have the 90 increments and free rotate. You can also change the existing shortcuts and buttons for these actions. The Tools | Settings module is your friend for this.
3. In Browser mode this is straightforward.
4. Yes. You must use the Thumbs/Browser mode. Also you can use the EXIF tag to rotate them automagically.
5. Yes.